# NullPointerException when accessing an internal Object attribute of an initialized object

Tags: java, oop, nullpointerexception

I have two classes, Car and Tire, with the following funcitons.

Tire:

```
public static class Tire{

  public boolean isBroken;
  public int milesLeft;

  public Tire(){
    isBroken = false;
    milesLeft = 100;
  }

  public void copyTire(Tire anotherTire){
    isBroken = anotherTire.isBroken;
    milesLeft = anotherTire.milesLeft;
  }

  public int getMilesLeft(){
    return milesLeft;
  }
}
```

Car

```
public static class Car{

  public boolean maintenance;
  public String name;
  public Tire tires[] = new Tire[MAX_TIRES];
  public Tire LF = new Tire();

  public Car(String name){
    maintenance = false;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
}
```

My problem is that I want to print the information (milesLeft) from all the tires of the car's array. I assumed it would work simply by using a for loop, but it doesn't and I dont know why.

This is what I tried:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_TIRES; i++){
   System.out.println("Tire nº"+i+": "+ i20.tires[i].getMilesLeft());
}
```

While printing an only tire, the LF we have in the car's class, there's no problem.

Any other errors you may see write them too, I've studied c++ but I'm starting with Java.

EDIT:

The error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at vehicles.main(vehicles.java:56)

The declaration of car with the 'main' function.

```
public static void main(String []args) { 
 Car i20 = new Car("i20");

 System.out.println("The name is " + i20.getName());
 System.out.println("The tires' status right now is:");
 for(int i = 0; i < MAX_TIRES; i++){
    System.out.println("Tire nº"+i+": "+ i20.tires[i].getMilesLeft());
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Are you adding any tires to the array before iterating?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at vehicles.main(vehicles.java:56) ERROR. And car: Car i20 = new Car("i20"); I thought that when creating a new car, it would create the tires too.

Comment: @EduardoGomez Post your whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that when creating a new car, it would create the tires too

Computers are stupid. You didn't tell it to create tyres whenever cars are created, so it didn't do it for you. That's why when you try to access the tyres, a `NullPointerException` is thrown. The tyres have not been created yet!

After you create your car, also create the tyres:

```
Car i20 = new Car("i20");
for (int i = 0 ; i < i20.tires.length l i++) {
    i20.tires[i] = new Trie();
}
```

Now the tyres are created. Then you can print the tyres using the for loop.

You can also put this tyre creation code in the constructor. Your `Car` class' constructor can look something like this:

```
public Car(String name){
    maintenance = false;
    this.name = name;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < this.tires.length ; i++) {
        this.tires[i] = new Tire();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say thanks but I cannot vote yet. This is the solution. I feel stupid.